# Ansible Pip Install python modules into vendor subdirectory using '--target'

Tags: python, pip, ansible, pypi

What is the Ansible pip module equalant of 'pip install --target vendor' ? Is 'virtualenv=' is the right choice to achieve this? Thanks!

```
- name: Download calibre-web dependencies into vendor subdirectory.
  command: pip install --target vendor -r ./requirements.txt
  args:
      chdir: /install/directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the `extra_args` option of the pip module. Please refer to example below

```
- name: install to vendor directory
  pip:
    requirements: requirements.txt
    chdir: /install/directory
    extra_args: --target vendor
```